# Drawing a graph with GraphViz in PHP

Tags: php, neo4j, graphviz

Good evening,

I am trying to figure out a way to display simple node/edge graphs from a Neo4J DB in PHP. I had a look at three.js, sigma and alchemy but those tools seem way to complex for such simple tasks. Then I found GraphViz which runs fine when I use the editor. But I was not able to find help when I wanted to use this from PHP. There is a pear package which seems not suitable anymore for PHP >5.0 (tried it and run into lots of errors (e.g. Non-static method System::mktemp() should not be called statically - there is also a thread here about this: [Graphviz not working with php 5.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818980/graphviz-not-working-with-php-5-3-2)) and I found a document http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gv.3php.pdf - but unfortunately it seems I cant deal with this.

Anybody has an example how to draw e.g. this:

```
 <?php
 require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';

 $gv = new Image_GraphViz();
 $gv->addEdge(array('wake up'        => 'visit bathroom'));
 $gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee'));
 $gv->image();
 ?>
```

(Source:http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php)

This code is from the pear package example but doesnt run - but maybe someone has an idea how to use this from PHP directly over the gv.php extension from GraphViz?

A GraphViz Example which runs fine in the editor:

```
graph graphname { 
                a -- b; 
                b -- c;
                b -- d;
                d -- a;
        }
```

But how to get PHP to talk with GraphViz and produce the output?

Any help is very appreciated, thanks.
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just use a javascript based dot renderer, e.g.

- https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/
- https://code.google.com/p/canviz/

Comment: Hi Michael, very appreciated, thats what I was looking for. While browsing the docu and testing a bit I couldnt find a way to make a node clickable and add an URL. Do you have any experience on how to add a <a href> to the nodes/edges?

Answer (score 0):

Result of my search:

I am using now http://visjs.org/ which suits good to my needs. Here is an example for the code: http://visjs.org/docs/network.html#Example

The problem to assign URLs to nodes has been solved by altering the javascript with a simple location.href on click.